# Let's look at this simple logical query

Tags: logical-deduction

.:
Aziz is talking with Rashid: " If I pass the exam on Friday , I will spend the weekend in the mountain. I will also bring my sister Nigora with me, If she feels ok". On Sunday morning Rashid meets Aziz in town. What is true?

A) Aziz did not pass the exam.

B) Nigora is not well.

C) Aziz did not pass the exam and Nigora is not well.

D) Aziz passed the exam, but Nigora did not want to go to the mountains.

E) Aziz passed the exam, but Nigora is not well.

Comment: Please don't use irrelevant tags. You can see what tags are meant to be  used for by hovering over them. (Also, this appears to be homework, judging by the `.:` at the beginning.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

answer is

> Aziz did not pass the exam
> Because, on Sunday morning Rashid meets Aziz in town(If he had passed, he should have been in mountains)

Comment: What about  Nigora

Comment: @user22143 here Aziz is saying 'if she feels ok', so I am guessing, at that time she was ill, but as he did not pass exams, it is irreverent now

Comment: Hint There is not written that Nigora is ill or not

Comment: @user22143 so, either option A or option C

Comment: This question has one and only one solution

Comment: @user22143 in that case, I am going with option A : Aziz did not pass the exam.

Comment: Can you express your answer in a way of mathematics

Comment: Your answer didn't contain full answer